# Slick slider: увеличение центральной картинки

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Нужно реализовать слайдер как на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Сделала при помощи slick слайдера, но нигде в настройках не нашла строчки, что бы картинка в центре увеличилась. Вот код

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,               
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
  //variableWidth: true,  
  
  arrows:true,
  nextArrow: '.project__next',
  prevArrow: '.project__prev',
});
```

```css
#container{
 max-width: 950px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.slider{
 max-width:600px;margin: 20px auto;
} 
.project__next img, .project__prev img{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
}
img {
  max-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="project__prev">
      <img src="https://media.msufcu.org/publicsites/publicsite/icons/arrow_left_gray.png">
    </div>
    <div class="slider">

      <div class="project__foto">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

      </div>
      <div class="project__foto">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

      </div>
      <div class="project__foto">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

      </div>
      <div class="project__foto">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

      </div>

</div>

  <div class="project__next">
      <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/5/C/M/6/i/right-grey-arrow.svg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы центральная картинка увеличилась в размере при клике на кнопки вперед и назад.

Comment: изменить ваш код или можно добавить свой?

Comment: @Избыток, да как Вам будет удобно. если мне будет не понятно - спрошу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Центрируйте слайдер `centerMode: true`, и стилизуйте класс `.slick-center`

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,               
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
  variableWidth: true,  
  arrows:true,
  nextArrow: '.project__next',
  prevArrow: '.project__prev',
});
```

```css
#container{
 max-width: 950px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.slider{
 max-width:600px;margin: 20px auto;
} 
.project__next img, .project__prev img{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
}
img {
  max-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #fff;

}
.slick-slide {
padding-top:20px;
}
.slick-center {
  padding-top:0;
}
.slick-center img {
  max-width:160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="project__prev">
        <img src="https://media.msufcu.org/publicsites/publicsite/icons/arrow_left_gray.png">
      </div>
      <div class="slider">

        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>

  </div>

    <div class="project__next">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/5/C/M/6/i/right-grey-arrow.svg">
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а кнопки вперед и назад можно сделать аккуратненько по бокам блока с картинками или придется в ручную задавать нужные центрирование используя position?

Comment: вручную задавать, лично для меня это проще во всех слайдерах, чем настройки искать

Comment: извините, но неожиданно обнаружила то что у меня два slick слайдера, где используется `centerMode:true,` соответственно .slick-center распространяется и на второй слайдер, где он не нужен. как исправить ситуацию подскажите.

Comment: зависит от ситуации. У вас что оба слайдера инициализируются одним скриптом? Если да - развести, добавить каждому уникальный id / класс и по нему объявлять слайдер. Нужный стилизовать - .name-slider .slick-center

Comment: ,вот посмотри пожалуйста. https://codepen.io/Samoilenko/pen/yEzmoG. для двух слайдеров разный класс. я немного не поняла

Comment: ну и нет проблем - у ненужного убрать centerMode:true

Comment: так проблема в том что слайдер с домиками увеличивает центральную картинку, а мне этого не нужно.а убрать не могу потому что если уберу, то у слайдера с котятами не будет центральная картинка больше. Вы, наверное, меня не так поняли. мне нужно использовать в двух слайдера centerMode:true. потому что второй слайдер должен быть вот такой как тут https://jsfiddle.net/kirana/3hfwrwmq/. он идет полукартинками по бокам. помогите разобраться

Comment: .slider .slick-center {
  padding-top:0;
}
.slider .slick-center img {
  max-width:230px;
}

Comment: блииинн. все так легко. спасибо Вам!!!